# Data structure for n*4 tables in java

Tags: java, data-structures

```
1   2   3   Canada
5   4   8   Australia
8   4   6   India
7   6   4   New Zealand
5   6   1   Zurich
3   3   8   New York
8   3   3   Philippines
6   3   2   Holland
```

How can I maintain the data structure in java 1.4 version for above requirement? Each row will be constructed with data from more than one database.

How to insert the row values in to that data structure?

At last after constructing the above table, the table has to sorted based on Country name .

Comment: "the table has to sorted based on Country name". That might be difficult as three rows have no country name in them :-)

Comment: Creat objects which have four members, one String and three short ints for example.

Comment: create a class that has four attributes, and also implements comparable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class like this:

```
public class MyDataRecord
{
    int a, b, c;
    String str;
}
```

Then hold an array or ArrayList of this type:

```
MyDataRecord[] records0 = new MyDataRecord[...];
List<MyDataRecord> records1 = new ArrayList<MyDataRecord>();
```